# Below Zero value issues while plotting interpolation graph

Tags: python, scipy

I use cubic spline to smooth the percentile graph. However the graph shows below zero values. Is there a way to limit or avoid below zero values. Since it is a probability graph does not make sense. below  is the part of the code.

```py
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline

dfplotP["distance"]=np.arange(0,10,r)

xnew = np.linspace(dfplotP["distance"].min(), dfplotP["distance"].max(), 1000)

spl = make_interp_spline(dfplotP["distance"], dfplotP[[a,b,c,d,e]], k=3)

power_smooth = spl(xnew)
plt.plot(xnew, power_smooth)
```

[image]

Comment: Ordinary splines aren't constrained to always be positive even if all y values are positive. Try "monotone splines" instead; a web search should find something. There may be other kinds of splines which are constrained to be positive, a web search could find something.

Comment: Please be aware of how to [properly use tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) when posting a question. At the very least, you need to tag the language you're asking about.